# BigQuery: Appending to existing table with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a table and need to add more records based on new data from Google Sheets.

I see how I can do it with union, meaning running

`Select * from (SELECT * from table),(select * from temp_table_from_sheets)`

I.e: querying old table, new table. Delete old table and save the result of the query as old table.

BUT IT MUST be possible to append instead of `BigQuery.Jobs.insert` only.

Can you help me please?

**EDIT - solution**

After getting the answer below, I googled a lot and eventually came up with the following **solution** in `Apps Script`:

```
var sql = 'select ...'
var projectId = '...'
var datasetId = '...'
var tableId = '...'

var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: sql,
        writeDisposition:'WRITE_APPEND',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }       
      }
    }
  };

   var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId)
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch?

Comment: If you solved it, then you should post that as an answer and accept it yourself. Don't put the solution in the question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [BigQuery API Basics - Managing Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#appending-data):

> ### Appending data
>
> You can load additional data into a table either from source files or
> by appending query results. Note that the schema of the loaded data
> must match the schema of the existing table, but you can [update the
> schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#updateschema) before appending.
>
> ...
>
> **To append data from a query result:**
>
> Run an asynchronous query, pass in the name of your existing table,
> and set `writeDisposition=WRITE_APPEND`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you told me. The links refer to pyton and java. I need a solution from the apps script. Thanks

Comment: I see you managed to use the info to figure out your solution- that 's great! Answers do not necessarily provide code: you said you didn't see a way to append a record, and this answer provides the document you hadn't found. The bare api is the same, regardless what language is used.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing Google Sheets content to BigQuery
[I found it here](https://www.wouternieuwerth.nl/how-to-push-google-sheets-to-bigquery/)

The tricky is sheet data to CSV.

```
var file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // This represents ALL the data

  var rows = file.getDataRange().getValues();

  var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n");

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, "text/csv");

  var data = blob.setContentType('application/octet-stream');


  // Create the data upload job.
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        skipLeadingRows: 1,
        writeDisposition: writeDispositionSetting
      }
    }
  };

  // send the job to BigQuery so it will run your query
  var runJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
  Logger.log(runJob.status);
  var jobId = runJob.jobReference.jobId
  Logger.log('jobId: ' + jobId);
  var status = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId);

  // wait for the query to finish running before you move on
  while (status.status.state === 'RUNNING') {
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    status = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId);
    Logger.log('Status: ' + status);
  }
  Logger.log('FINNISHED!');
}
```